# Simulating Button Click to UI class from console

Tags: c++, command-line, button, mfc, dialog

I'm working on a project that currently exists as a user-interactive application w/ MFC dialog boxes.  I have to extend it so that it can be used as an application that accepts command-line parameters.  To do that, i have to call the method that is mapped to the button click of one of the MFC-based dialog boxes from another class.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crate a public method in the class containing your button-click-method, and let it call the private button-click-method. You got me? ;-)

Comment: Yeah!  I think I got it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create and expose a public method in your Form class that will call the button click handler.

Header declaration:

```
public:
    void DoClick();
```

Definition:

```
void YourDlg::DoClick()
{
    OnBnClickedOk(); // for example
}
```

Also remember that the dialog class needs to be instantiated when you call it.